# How can i Pass data from controller to components vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

i want to show client in form  select but nothing happen this my from and components script [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SQIx.png)

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0dsr.png)

Comment: Instead of providing links to images of the code. Please include the code in the question.

Comment: there is two common way to do that first bypass this data as a prop from your view, or by get this data from `ajax` request

Comment: Please add your code here, not the link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

The v-for loop should be in the option tag not the select tag